# Proof for convergence of recursive series: $a_1 = \frac\pi4$, and $a_n =\frac12 \tan(a_{n-1})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

If I define a sequence $a_n$:
$$
a_1 = \frac{\pi}{4},~~ a_n =\frac{1}{2} \tan(a_{n-1})
$$
and then define a series:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_n
$$

I can see why it converges, by the comparison test for $n\gt 6$
$a_n < \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and we know $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges as a p-series so
$a_n$ must converge.

But how do I formally prove it?

Comment: What do you think is informal about your argument?

Comment: IMO, this is no proof at all. "I can see by the comparison test" is not a sufficient argument and I'd be curious to know how you established this unexpected upper bound.

Comment: @aryamanMaithani That i can argue for n = 6,7,8,9,10,even 20 but if this function behaves in some odd way at n=10^1000 then i would be wrong i think.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well its kind of intuition and im not really sure so thats why im asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\tan''(x)=2\sec^2(x)\tan(x)\ge0$ for $0\le x\le\frac\pi4$, $\tan(x)$ is convex for $0\le x\le\frac\pi4$. Therefore, for $0\le x\le\frac\pi4$,
$$
\tan(x)\le\frac4\pi x\tag1
$$
Inductively, we get
$$
a_n\le\frac\pi4\left(\frac2\pi\right)^{n-1}\tag2
$$
Thus, the series converges by comparison to a geometric series with ratio between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For sufficiently small positive angles,

$$\tan a<1.1\,a$$ and by induction the series is bounded by a converging geometric one (of common ratio $\dfrac{1.1}2$).